# Settings.settings in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
Settings.settings
<Setting Name="user_create" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
<Value Profile="(Default)">A user {0} is created.</Value>
</Setting>

UserServices.cs
userService.DescriptionMessage= Settings.Default.user_create + userName;
```

If user created the name "Michael"

Now the value of DescriptionMessage is "A user {0} is created.Michael".

I would like to get the value of DescriptionMessage as the following.

"A user Michael is created.".

How should I update in the service?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work...

```
userService.DescriptionMessage= string.Format(Settings.Default.user_create, userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `string.Format()` to replace `{0}` with `userName`:

```
userService.DescriptionMessage = string.Format(Settings.Default.user_create, userName);
```